# Apache Cxf Webclient Doen't Work As Expected in Tomee 8

Tags: cxf, apache-tomee, cxf-client, tomee-8

I am trying to get jwk keyset from google for use with Apache Cxf OIDC and Jose Libs. The code works fine when I run it on a stand alone main method.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs", Arrays.asList(new JsonWebKeysProvider()), true).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        JsonWebKeys keys = client.get(JsonWebKeys.class);
        keys.getKeys().forEach(key -> {
            System.out.println("****************************************************************************");
            System.out.println("ID........." + key.getKeyId());
            System.out.println("Alg........" + key.getAlgorithm());
            System.out.println("Key Type..." + key.getKeyType());
            System.out.println("Use........" + key.getPublicKeyUse());
        });

    }

}
```

The ID, algorithm, key type and use is printed properly meaning that the keys are property populated.

Sample output:

```
****************************************************************************
ID.........79c809dd1186cc228c4baf9358599530ce92b4c8
Alg........RS256
Key Type...RSA
Use........sig
****************************************************************************
ID.........17d55ff4e10991d6b0efd392b91a33e54c0e218b
Alg........RS256
Key Type...RSA
Use........sig
```

pom.xml extract for Main class.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-sso-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The same code however doesn't work when deployed in Tomee 8.

```
@WebServlet(name = "NewServlet", urlPatterns = {"/x"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        final WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs", Arrays.asList(new JsonWebKeysProvider()), true).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        JsonWebKeys keys = client.get(JsonWebKeys.class);
        keys.getKeys().forEach(key -> {
            writer.println("****************************************************************************");
            writer.println("ID........." + key.getKeyId());
            writer.println("Alg........" + key.getAlgorithm());
            writer.println("Key Type..." + key.getKeyType());
            writer.println("Use........" + key.getPublicKeyUse());
        });

    }
}
```

The ID, algorithm, key type and use is null  when this code runs in Tomee 8. I have added cxf oidc lib and jose jars are installed in tomee/lib folder.

Sample output:

```
****************************************************************************
ID.........null
Alg........null
Key Type...null
Use........null
****************************************************************************
ID.........null
Alg........null
Key Type...null
Use........null
```

pom.xml extract for the servlet.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0-3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-sso-oidc</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that when Webclient is created inside tomee, it picks up bus properties provided by tomee which was causing JsonWebKeysProvider not to be invoked.

In my case below is the correct way to create the client inside tomee.

```
JAXRSClientFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
sf.setAddress("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs");
sf.setProvider(new JsonWebKeysProvider());
sf.setBus(new ExtensionManagerBus());
```

Calling **sf.setBus(new ExtensionManagerBus());** ensures tomee provided values/properties aren't picked up.